# Подскажите как поместить `owl carusel` внутрь модального окна

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, всплывающее-окно, карусель

Как поместить `owl carusel` внутрь модального окна?

Просто на место контента добавить не получается.

Демонстрация в [фидле](http://jsfiddle.net/9nuhnbbv/65/)

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
      navigation: true
    });

    $("#owl-demo2").owlCarousel({
      navigation: true
    });

  });
```

```css
#owl-demo .item {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #42BDC2;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#owl-demo2 .item {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00FF00;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#HoastedModal" class="btn btn-info">Open Modal</a>

<div id="HoastedModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 id="modal-label">Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--modal-content-->
  </div>
  <!--modal-dialog-->
</div>
<!--modal-->

<div class="tabbable">
  <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
      <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item">
          <h1>1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>3</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>4</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>5</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>6</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>7</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>8</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>9</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>10</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>11</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>12</h1>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
      <div id="owl-demo2" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item">
          <h1>1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>3</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>4</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>5</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>6</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>7</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>8</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>9</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>10</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>11</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>12</h1>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: за что кто-то ставит минусы - не пойму..?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
      navigation: true
    });

    $("#owl-demo2").owlCarousel({
      navigation: true
    });

  });
```

```css
#owl-demo .item {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #42BDC2;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#owl-demo2 .item {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00FF00;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>


<a data-toggle="modal" href="#HoastedModal" class="btn btn-info">Open Modal</a>

<div id="HoastedModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 id="modal-label">Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item">
          <h1>1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>3</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>4</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>5</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>6</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>7</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>8</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>9</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>10</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>11</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>12</h1>
        </div>

      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--modal-content-->
  </div>
  <!--modal-dialog-->
</div>
<!--modal-->

<div class="tabbable">
  <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
      
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
      <div id="owl-demo2" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item">
          <h1>1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>3</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>4</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>5</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>6</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>7</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>8</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>9</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>10</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>11</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>12</h1>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

работает вроде как, проверь очерёдность загруски JS файлов
1- Jquery
2- Bootstrap
3- Owl

Comment: а что собственно работает? вы условие читали хоть?

Comment: Самому скопировать секцию с каруселью в модал не получается?

Comment: нет, не получается я ж об этом и пишу - модальное окно не открывается. а что вы записали и чем это отличается от моего кода я не пойму

Comment: У вас карусель с модалами работает на базе 3-х CSS и 3-х JS библиотек которые у вас не загруженны В этом эдиторе модал открывается только когда демо на весь экран открываеш